# Array Manipulation to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter

I have the following array:

```
(array([[5.8205872e+07, 2.0200601e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 2.1500000e+02,
         5.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00],
        [5.7929117e+07, 2.0200601e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 1.5000000e+02,
         5.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00],
        [5.8178782e+07, 2.0200601e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 1.5750000e+02,
         5.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00],
        [5.7936230e+07, 2.0210228e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 1.8000000e+02,
         4.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00],
        [5.8213574e+07, 2.0210228e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 6.9500000e+02,
         4.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00],
        [2.5693916e+07, 2.0210228e+07, 1.6700000e+02, 4.8518000e+02,
         4.0000000e+01, 5.0000000e+00]]),
 array([[ 0.46666667,  7.16666667],
        [ 0.51724138,  5.17241379],
        [ 0.73333333,  5.25      ],
        [ 0.34285714,  5.14285714],
        [ 1.18918919, 18.78378378],
        [ 1.26315789, 12.76789474]]))
```

I would like to transform it to a data frame that has 8 columns and six rows in total.
I tried to do : `pd.Dataframe(my_array)` but the result is just two rows like this:

```
0   [[58205872.0, 20200601.0, 167.0, 30.0, 1.0, 10...
1   [[0.4666666666666667, 7.166666666666667], [0.5...
```

How can I achieve what is described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to concatenate your two arrays (indeed you do have two arrays assigned to `my_array`) and then turn the result into a dataframe. What about first using [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
>>> your_two_arrays = (..., ...)
>>> a = np.hstack(your_two_arrays)
>>> a.shape
(6, 8)
```

and finally [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=a)
            0           1      2       3     4    5         6          7
0  58205872.0  20200601.0  167.0  215.00  50.0  5.0  0.466667   7.166667
1  57929117.0  20200601.0  167.0  150.00  50.0  5.0  0.517241   5.172414
2  58178782.0  20200601.0  167.0  157.50  50.0  5.0  0.733333   5.250000
3  57936230.0  20210228.0  167.0  180.00  40.0  5.0  0.342857   5.142857
4  58213574.0  20210228.0  167.0  695.00  40.0  5.0  1.189189  18.783784
5  25693916.0  20210228.0  167.0  485.18  40.0  5.0  1.263158  12.767895
```

---

> [...] the result is just two rows like this: [...]

The data that you were providing to `pd.Dataframe` when doing `pd.Dataframe(my_array)` was a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) of two objects. Hence the two rows you got (and one column), i.e. one per array.

Comment: Any question @Peter ?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!